# Why is Entity Framework missing the last s in a table that ends with 'Status'

Tags: entity-framework

This is a really weird error, I have looked online and can not see any obvious reasons why this is happening.

I am using Database First Entity Framework version 5 and have added 4 tables called:

- WorkStatus
- JobStatus
- SubJobStatus
- SubJobStageStatus

JobStatus, SubJobStatus and SubJobStageStatus each has a foreign key constraint to WorkStatus.

I have updated my edmx to include these tables but for some reason each table is missing the last s from the word Status. So the tables and their navigation properties are now called:

- WorkStatu
- JobStatu
- SubJobStatu
- SubJobStageStatu

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"-Status" is being interpreted as a plural, and Entity Framework is being "helpful" by de-pluralizing.

For example, if you have a table called "Customers" EF will generate an entity called "Customer", which is in fact nicer in code:

```
var customer = new Customer();
```

It isn't working out so well in your case; your tables are already singular.

You can rename your tables to "-Statuses" or update the names in the designer or disable pluralization:

Under `Tools > Options`
[image]